# Logger proxy class for isolating dependency on Logging framework

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, proxy, slf4j

We are in process of developing a new Java EE application. For logging we re going to use slf4j bridge so that there in no dependency on any particular framework. I am thinking of taking this approach to the  next level and write a logger proxy class, so that the slf4j code is not spread accross the application

```
public class MyLogger implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -9108178019072752331L;
private String loggerName;

private Logger logger;

public MyLogger (String loggerName) {
    this.loggerName = loggerName;
    initLogger();
}

private void initLogger() {
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);
}

public void error(String messageFormat, Object ...argArray) {
    logger.error(messageFormat, argArray);
}

public void info(String messageFormat, Object ...argArray) {
    logger.info(messageFormat, argArray);
}

public void warn(String messageFormat, Object ...argArray) {
    logger.warn(messageFormat, argArray);
}

public void debug(String messageFormat, Object ...argArray) {
    logger.debug(messageFormat, argArray);
}
```

}

and to use the above class

```
private static final MyLogger logger = new MyLogger (
        TestClass.class.getCanonicalName());
```

and call the methods as follows:

```
logger.info("Audit Log :: ", auditLog.toString());
```

Would this be right approach to do it? Or should I write a a factory class too?

Comment: You think it's worthwhile to write an abstraction (your code) of an abstraction (SLF4J)?

Comment: Probably not. But was reading the SLF4J docs. The abstraction that SLF4J provides is really amazing. We don't have to depend on any partcular logging framework, but SLF4J. Was wondering if we could almost completely remove dependency on any third-party framework. Then this thought came to me about abstracting out SLF4J itself.

Comment: Well, you're not really removing the dependency if you're still using their jars are you? Unless you're sticking with stock java.util.logging, there's zero benefit to rolling your own here. Just roll with the goodness of SLF4J and be merry

Comment: there is no real merrit to wrap something with the exact same API. Generally you want to hide implementation details which are dependend on your real implementation for a specific use case which is not provided by the SLF4J API.